# XElement and value for boolean attributes

Tags: c#, boolean, xelement

Take for example:

- ```
  new XAttribute("Completed", true)
  ```
- ```
  studentElement.SetAttributeValue("Included", studentItem.Type != string.Empty);
  ```

In both instances, the resulting XML file will have ether `"true` or `"false"`. Is it possible to set up the `XDocument` so that all `bool` attribute values are saved as `0` and `1` respecively?

I know I can do:

- ```
  new XAttribute("Completed", "1")
  ```
- ```
  studentElement.SetAttributeValue("Included",
       studentItem.Type != string.Empty ? "1" : "0");
  ```

Is there a simple alternative?

---

I am using `Load` and `Save` to read / write to XML file (`XDocument`).

Comment: [It doesn't look like it](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.Xml/System/Xml/XmlConvert.cs,82c1e735c6f49e18)

Comment: @canton7 Thanks for the link. Fair enough. Just wondered in the `XDocument` had some control over how they were written to / from the file.

Comment: [This constructor](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XAttribute.cs,54) calls [this method](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XContainer.cs,4390095c431478d1), which unconditionally calls the other method I linked -- so there's no way to configure that call chain I'm afraid